# Is there any way append values to a Pandas Dataframe using partial string matching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

| Titles |
| --- |
| The Ice Age Adventures of Buck Wild |
| The Beatles: Get Back – The Rooftop Concert |
| Turning Red |
| Chip 'n Dale: Rescue Rangers |
| Zombies 3 |

And a list that looks like this:

```
[
'<img src=posters/turning_red.jpeg alt=red>', 
'<img src=posters/ice_age_adventures_of_buck_wild.jpeg alt=ice_age>', 
'<img src=posters/chip_n_dale_rescue_rangers.jpeg alt=rangers>', 
'<img src=posters/beatles_get_back__the_rooftop_concert.jpeg alt=beatles>', 
'<img src=posters/zombies_three.jpeg alt=zombies>'
]
```

Is there any way (without some crazy regex) to append this list to the Dataframe so that the items match the most similar row?

I'm looking for something like this:

| Posters | Titles |
| --- | --- |
| `<img src=posters/ice_age_adventures_of_buck_wild.jpeg alt=ice_age>` | The Ice Age Adventures of Buck Wild |
| `<img src=posters/beatles_get_back__the_rooftop_concert.jpeg alt=beatles>` | The Beatles: Get Back – The Rooftop Concert |
| `<img src=posters/turning_red.jpeg alt=red>` | Turning Red |
| `<img src=posters/chip_n_dale_rescue_rangers.jpeg alt=rangers>` | Chip 'n Dale: Rescue Rangers |
| `<img src=posters/zombies_three.jpeg alt=zombies>` | Zombies 3 |

Comment: It looks like you should be able to write a simple `stubify()` function that takes a title and returns the corresponding stub in the URL. You can use that when merging.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly matching your expected result but you can create a specific function to handle regular string conversion from image tag to title and apply it to a new column using `df.apply(<function>, axis=1)`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Posters": [
    '<img src=posters/turning_red.jpeg alt=red>', 
    '<img src=posters/ice_age_adventures_of_buck_wild.jpeg alt=ice_age>', 
    '<img src=posters/chip_n_dale_rescue_rangers.jpeg alt=rangers>', 
    '<img src=posters/beatles_get_back__the_rooftop_concert.jpeg alt=beatles>', 
    '<img src=posters/zombies_three.jpeg alt=zombies>'
]})

def conversion(row):
    return row['Posters'].split('/')[1].split('.jpeg')[0].replace('_', ' ').title()

df['Titles'] = df.apply(conversion, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: You don't need `.apply`, you could do `df['Titles'] = df['Posters'].str.split('/').str[1].str.split('.jpeg').str[0].str.replace('__', ' - ').str.replace('_', ' ').str.title()` instead.